# Forced layout bubble chart with large data set problem

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there some algorithm for building forced layout bubble chart with groups (like this http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/force-bubbles/) but with the huge dataset. The main problem for me is selecting the right spaces, for this example, they use some static offsets. But when you have groups with 10k bubbles near some with only 100 they usually collide and overlay titles. Probably you can decide with something like this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle but not sure how to deal with different sizes

[Example of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYDMH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take into consideration that:

1. SVG can display a limited number of elements (10K is a recommended limit)
2. A human eye can recognize a few hundreds of visual items on the screen (and focus on a dozen, not more)

I suggest to use the Google Maps approach, i.e. define a virtual space and display only a relevant part of it according to the viewport position and zoom level.

```js
const space = {
 top: -25000, 
 left: -25000, 
 right: 25000, 
 bottom: 25000
};

const generateRandomCircles = count => {
 let circles = [];
 const spaceWidth  = space.right - space.left;
 const spaceHeight  = space.bottom - space.top;
 for (let id = 1; id <= count; id++) {
  const x = space.left + Math.random() * spaceWidth;
  const y = space.top + Math.random() * spaceHeight;

  const r = 30 + Math.random() * 70;
  const c = () => 128 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 128);
  const color = `rgb(${c()},${c()},${c()})`;
  const circle = {id, x, y, r, color};
  circles.push(circle);
 }
 return circles.sort((a, b) => b.r - a.r);
};

const svg = d3.select('svg')
const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
const circles = generateRandomCircles(50000);

const virtualToScreen = (point, transform) => {
 const x = (point.x + width/2) * transform.k + transform.x;
 const y = (point.y + height/2) * transform.k + transform.y;
 return {x, y};
};

const screenToVirtual = (point, transform) => {
 const x = (point.x - transform.x) / transform.k - width/2;
 const y = (point.y - transform.y) / transform.k - height/2;
 return {x, y};
};

const drawMarker = (pos, label, isVertical, showLabel=true) => {
 svg.append('line')
  .classed('marker-line', true)
  .attr('x1', isVertical ? pos : 0)
  .attr('x2', isVertical ? pos : width)
  .attr('y1', isVertical ? 0 : pos)
  .attr('y2', isVertical ? height : pos)
  .style('stroke', '#789');
 
 if(showLabel) {
  svg.append('text')
   .classed('marker-label', true)
   .text(label)
   .attr('x', isVertical ? pos : 3)
   .attr('y', isVertical ? 14 : pos + 4)
   .attr('text-anchor', isVertical ? 'middle' : 'start')
   .style('fill', '#def');

  svg.append('text')
   .classed('marker-label', true)
   .text(label)
   .attr('x', isVertical ? pos : width - 3)
   .attr('y', isVertical ? height - 4 : pos + 4)
   .attr('text-anchor', isVertical ? 'middle' : 'end')
   .style('fill', '#def');
  }
};

const scaleFactors = () =>  {
 let factors = [1];
 let multiplier = 1;
 for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
  multiplier *= index % 3 == 1 ? 2.5 : 2;
  factors.push(multiplier);
 }
 return factors.reverse();
}

const updateMarkers = transform => {
 svg.selectAll('.marker-label,.marker-line').remove();
  
 const factor = width / 5 / transform.k;
 const step = scaleFactors()
  .find(step => step < factor) || 1;
 
 const stl = {x: 0, y: 0};
 const sbr = {x: width, y: height};
 const vtl = screenToVirtual(stl, transform);
 const vbr = screenToVirtual(sbr, transform);
 
 const fromX = Math.ceil(vtl.x / step) * step;
 const toX = Math.floor(vbr.x / step) * step;
 for (let x = fromX; x <= toX; x += step) {
  const pos = virtualToScreen({x, y: 0}, transform);
  drawMarker(pos.x, x, true, x > fromX && x < toX);
 }
 
 const fromY = Math.ceil(vtl.y / step) * step;
 const toY = Math.floor(vbr.y / step) * step;
 for (let y = fromY; y <= toY; y += step) {
  const pos = virtualToScreen({x: 0, y}, transform);
  drawMarker(pos.y, y, false);
 }
};

const updateView = transform => {
 const mapper = circle => {
  const point = virtualToScreen(circle, transform);
  const r = circle.r * transform.k;
  return {...circle, ...point, r};
 };
 
 const circleIsVisible = circle => 
  (circle.x + circle.r > 0 && 
  circle.x - circle.r < width &&
  circle.y + circle.r > 0 && 
  circle.y - circle.r < height &&
  circle.r > 2); 

 const start = performance.now();
 const filtered = circles.map(mapper)
  .filter(circleIsVisible);
  
 const all = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(filtered, d => d.id)
  
 const added = all.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .style('fill', d => d.color)
  .style('opacity', 0.5)
  
 added.merge(all)
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y)
  .attr('r', d => d.r);
  
 all.exit().remove();
 
 updateMarkers(transform);
};

const delta = () => {
 return -d3.event.deltaY * (d3.event.deltaMode ? 120 : 1) / 5000;
}

const onZoom = () => updateView(d3.event.transform);
 
const svgZoom = d3.zoom()
  .wheelDelta(delta)
  .clickDistance(10)
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
  .on('zoom', onZoom);
svg.call(svgZoom);

updateView({x: 0, y: 0, k: 1});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  background-color: #123;
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='500' height='300'>
</svg>
```